# What is an appropriate transformation for the response variable "size"?

Tags: self-study, biostatistics, hierarchical-bayesian

I plan to implement a hierarchical Bayesian model in an MCMC algorithm for a side project that I am working on.

I need to use Gaussian likelihood and priors for vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. I am considering an inverse-Chi squared distribution for my $\sigma^2$ term.

Thus, my model is:

$y_i \sim N(\textbf{x}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)$

$\beta_i \sim N(0,100^2)$

$\sigma^2 \sim IC(\nu)$

I am tasked with choosing a transformation of the response variable $y_i$, which indicates size for an individual female. To be quite honest, I do not even know where to begin in determining a transformation of $y_i$ to be used in analysis. It seems that the values of $y_i$ would be unambiguous.

Side questions:

Do the hyperparameters seem fair to you?

I do not want to keep using IG. Does my choice of Inverse-Chi squared make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a log-transformation, since biomass is strictly positive and the data were apparently right-skewed.